# hadoop reducer progress 100% but doesn't end

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running one hadoop job with 16 reduce tasks. (hadoop-1.2.1)

Some of them have 100% progress, but they don't end. 
they just stuck at 100% and job clean up : pending.
And their status displays only 'reduce > reduce'.

I guess this problem occurs because the job writes too many multiple outputs. (about 50~100 multiple outputs)
But it's just my guess. I don't know exactly that writing many multiple outputs causes this problem. 
Could anyone tell me what causes this problem in detail? 
I searched a lot for this, but I could not find a clear answer.

Best regards.

Comment: your guess is reasonable. disk I/O is very often the bottleneck of a MapReduce job.

Comment: If my guess is right, what is the difference between writing many multiple outputs and many values to part-r-000XX files of each reducer? and it seems that it's always stuck at closing multiple output files not writing values to the files. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the task logs? You should be able to tell what the task is doing. For instance, you should see if it is merging files.

Also, make note of how much data the reducers are processing. Are the reducers that are completing processing less data than the ones that are not completing in the same time? If so then this points to reducer skew (data skew) they are doing more work than the others.

Comment: I checked the tasks' logs and found that some of them printed 'java.io.IOException: JvmValidate Failed' error. I think there is some problem in my code. I'll take a look more. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I looked at the log more. The error I mentioned above isn't at stuck phase. I couldn't find any errors after the progress got 100%. But it printed '1.0% reduce > reduce', and after 15 mins, it printed 'Task attempt_201709141045_0002_r_000008_0 is in commit-pending'. There is a blank for 15 minutes.